# Creating an administrator webpage for a Facebook Flash game

Tags: facebook, admin

I am creating a [Facebook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook) [Flash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash) game where the application will be run on my server and will be displayed in Facebook using an iFrame. My question is: How do I administer the application. I'd like to do things such as see reports, the ability to ban / kick users, etc. How would I go about doing this? Does Facebook provide any in-built facility to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to create a separate page to administer your database for banning of users/ reading the daily user amount etc etc